# deploy asp.net solution to multiple hosting systems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I am working on an asp.net solution and using my remote testing environment with godaddy.
The application is ready for deployment so i have two questions:
1- since the database will be different , i am thinking about using a different Web.config , but not sure how does it work and how to implement that so i can choose easily which web config depending on the poriject/solution

2- the solution i am working on could be personalized and deployed to multiple clients , so each client version will be different (Like the logo and other stuff not the design and functionality), do i need to create separate solution for each client or should i create a separate website project instead?

what's best practices in this case

Answer (score 2):

Use configurations and associated config transforms. By default, your project gets a `Debug` and `Release` configuration, but you can add additional configurations. Then, for each configuration, you can have a separate `Web.config` transform, `Web.Server1.config`, `Web.Server2.config`, `Web.Client1.config`, `Web.Client2.config`, etc. When publishing, you choose which configuration you want to publish with, and that associated transform will be run against the `Web.config` file to change out connection strings, app settings, whatever.

For more information see: [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project | MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)